# Europass CV in (Xe)LaTeX

Tags: xetex, packages, templates, cv, europecv

I was requested to re-write my CV in the Europass format, and I would like to do it using (preferably) XeLaTeX. I came across the `europecv` package, which seems to do the job just fine, but I would like to know if there are any better, more complete and up-to-date package to achieve a nice result.

Answer (score 8):

[`europecv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/europecv) is indeed the package to use to typeset a Europass CV in LateX. If you're looking for some information, I wrote a post on my blog about it a few years back: http://www.raphink.info/2007/08/europecv-latex-cv-class.html

The post links to an example.

Comment: This is the nicest Europass CV I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the class `europecv2013` (see [europasscv-template](https://github.com/auino/europasscv-template) project on GitHub), with better support to pictures (also including the possibility to embed a qrcode) and better support to academic curricula (i.e. support to scientific results).