# UK CV templates

Tags: templates, moderncv

I am looking for a UK CV style layout in LaTex, the only ones I seem to be able to find are all American based. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Duplicate? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26164/europass-cv-in-xelatex

Comment: What exactly do are you looking for in a "UK style" layout?

Comment: letter head layout at top and with address and details centered,  then sever sections down the left hand-side containing skills, qualifications etc....

Comment: If you can share a picture of what you mean, it might be easier for people here to help :)